# Erro de cálculo de intervalo de dias entre duas datas usando diff em PHP

Tags: php, datetime, data, diff

Estou tendo uma diferença de valores ao calcular o intervalo de dias entre duas datas. Eu tenho o seguinte:

```
$data1 = new DateTime('2019-06-10');
$data2 = new DateTime('9999-12-31');
```

Se eu utilizar o seguinte comando eu tenho um valor:

```
echo $intervalo->format('%a');
```

Isso mostra na tela: `2914797`.

Mas caso eu utilize:

```
echo $intervalo->d;
```

Eu tenho o valor de: `21`.

O correto é mesmo utilizar a primeira forma? Ou tem algo errado na segunda forma de cálculo do intervalo de dias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao calcular a diferença entre duas datas usando [`DateTime::diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php), o resultado é um [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), e esta classe "quebra" a diferença em vários campos (anos, meses, dias, etc). Para entender melhor, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
$data1 = new DateTime('2019-06-10');
$data2 = new DateTime('9999-12-31');
$intervalo = $data1->diff($data2);
echo $intervalo->format('%y anos, %m meses, %d dias');
```

A saída é:

```
7980 anos, 6 meses, 21 dias
```

Os formatos `%y`, `%m` e `%d` correspondem, respectivamente, aos campos `y`, `m` e `d` do `DateInterval`. Ou seja, o código abaixo gera a mesma saída do exemplo anterior:

```
// 7980 anos, 6 meses, 21 dias
echo $intervalo->y . ' anos, ' . $intervalo->m . ' meses, ' . $intervalo->d . ' dias';
```

Já o formato `%a` traz o **total** de dias correspondente a esta duração (no caso, o total de dias que corresponde a 7980 anos, 6 meses e 21 dias). Veja todos os formatos disponíveis na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php).

Então se quiser saber a quantidade total de dias, use o formato `%a` (ou chame diretamente `$intervalo->days`). Se quiser a diferença devidamente "quebrada" em anos, meses e dias, use os campos `y`, `m` e `d` (ou os formatos `%y`, `%m` e `%d`).